# What customizations do OLE and MSHTML support?

Tags: c++, winapi, ole, mshtml

I found some examples of use MSHTML to render HTML in WinAPI application (w/o MFC, UWP etc.), like [this example](https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/cpp-MSHTML). I have no experience with OLE and MSHTML, so I want to know can I implement some things before I'll try to dive into it. Specifically, I need to:

- Handle link clicks, for example - launch external browser from my app, or do some other actions;
- Use checkboxes and handle their toggling (for example, to set some vars in my app);
- Disable text selection;
- HTML should be rendered in my window, I mean I want to place it in my window just like any other control. It also should support HiDPI scaling.

Comment: MSHTML is Internet Explorer engine so at rendering level you have access to links, clicks checkbox, etc. basically all what IE provides. But it's not pure rendering, it's *hosting* (you're *hosting* IE somehow).  I wouldn't invest too much in that technology now that IE is deprecated. All this is ancient tech, total HiDPI support is probably more critical in that regard. However for simple things, it's still working. Your example points to this which demonstrates how to host it in your window. Google for "mshtml hosting c++"

Comment: The long term replacement for MSHTML is [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), so you might want to evaluate whether that works for you. I haven't used either extensively and don't know what level of detail you get with respect to events at the API. You may have to inject ECMAScript to communicate between user input and the hosting application.